# actionscript Storing a value after a button is clicked (followup)

Tags: actionscript

Recently I posted a question on this forum (https://stackoverflow.com/a/34785776/5714593), and quickly got an anwer to my question. Unfortunately, I ran into some (other) issues. So could Akmozo, or any other user help me out?

I've been testing with your script And used it for a greater part. What I had to do is to change de for statement to place the buttons. This because I want to give them each a different look and placement, kinda like a puzzle. Below you'll find the script again. In the following script, it won't place button 9 and 10. While testing it with traces, it seems to be placed but it does not show. Could you plase be of assistance once again?

And while were at it. The FLV playback loads in a strange location the first time. After clicking the button again it loads properly in the middle of the stage.
Also I would like to add a dropshadow to the FLV playback so it kinda overlays on the buttons.

Help would be greatly appreciated. I've tried to add an picture or what it should look like here [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsLp9.jpg)

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import fl.video.*;
    import flash.filters.*;

    public class Main extends MovieClip 
    {
        private var drukknopje1:knopje1;
        private var drukknopje2:knopje2;
        private var drukknopje3:knopje3;
        private var drukknopje4:knopje4;
        private var drukknopje5:knopje5;
        private var drukknopje6:knopje6;
        private var drukknopje7:knopje7;
        private var drukknopje8:knopje8;
        private var drukknopje9:knopje9;
        private var drukknopje10:knopje10;
        private const BUTTONS_NUM:int = 10;
        private const BUTTONS_Y:int = 70;
        private const BUTTONS_SUFFIX:String = 'inst_knop';
        private const VIDEOS:Array = ['1.flv', '2.flv', '3.flv', '4.flv', '5.flv', '6.flv', '7.flv', '8.flv', '9.flv', '10.flv'];
        private var videoclip:FLVPlayback = new FLVPlayback();

        public function Main() 
        {
            createButtons();
        }   

        private function createButtons(): void 
        {
            drukknopje1 = new knopje1();
            drukknopje1.name = BUTTONS_SUFFIX + ('1');
            drukknopje1.x = 0
            drukknopje1.y = 0;
            addChild(drukknopje1);
            drukknopje1.buttonMode = true;
            drukknopje1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playVideo);

            drukknopje2 = new knopje2();
            drukknopje2.name = BUTTONS_SUFFIX + ('2');
            drukknopje2.x = 247 ;
            drukknopje2.y = 0;
            addChild(drukknopje2);
            drukknopje2.buttonMode = true;
            drukknopje2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playVideo);

            drukknopje3 = new knopje3();
            drukknopje3.name = BUTTONS_SUFFIX + ('3');
            drukknopje3.x = 760;
            drukknopje3.y = 0;
            addChild(drukknopje3);
            drukknopje3.buttonMode = true;
            drukknopje3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playVideo);

            drukknopje4 = new knopje4();
            drukknopje4.name = BUTTONS_SUFFIX + ('4');
            drukknopje4.x = 1489;
            drukknopje4.y = 0;
            addChild(drukknopje4);
            drukknopje4.buttonMode = true;
            drukknopje4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playVideo);

            drukknopje5 = new knopje5();
            drukknopje5.name = BUTTONS_SUFFIX + ('5');
            drukknopje5.x = 461;
            drukknopje5.y = 394;
            addChild(drukknopje5);
            drukknopje5.buttonMode = true;
            drukknopje5.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playVideo);

            drukknopje6 = new knopje6();
            drukknopje6.name = BUTTONS_SUFFIX + ('6');
            drukknopje6.x = 898;
            drukknopje6.y = 449 ;
            addChild(drukknopje6);
            drukknopje6.buttonMode = true;
            drukknopje6.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playVideo);

            drukknopje7 = new knopje7();
            drukknopje7.name = BUTTONS_SUFFIX + ('7');
            drukknopje7.x =  0;
            drukknopje7.y = 583;
            addChild(drukknopje7);
            drukknopje7.buttonMode = true;
            drukknopje7.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playVideo);

            drukknopje8 = new knopje8();
            drukknopje8.name = BUTTONS_SUFFIX + ('8');
            drukknopje8.x = 444;
            drukknopje8.y = 817;
            addChild(drukknopje8);
            drukknopje8.buttonMode = true;
            drukknopje8.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playVideo);

            drukknopje9 = new knopje9();
            drukknopje9.name = BUTTONS_SUFFIX + ('9');
            drukknopje9.x = 450;
            drukknopje9.y = 1375;
            addChild(drukknopje9);
            trace(drukknopje9.name);
            trace(drukknopje9.x);
            trace(drukknopje9.y);
            drukknopje9.buttonMode = true;
            drukknopje9.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playVideo);

            drukknopje10 = new knopje10();
            drukknopje10.name = BUTTONS_SUFFIX + ('10');
            drukknopje10.x = 418;
            drukknopje10.y = 1920;
            addChild(drukknopje10);
            trace(drukknopje10.name);
            trace(drukknopje10.x);
            trace(drukknopje10.y);
            drukknopje10.buttonMode = true;
            drukknopje10.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playVideo);             
        }

        private function playVideo(event:MouseEvent):void 
        {   
            // get button's index, for example : 7 for the button called     "inst_knop7"
            var button_index:int =               int((event.currentTarget.name).substr(BUTTONS_SUFFIX.length)) - 1;   

            // play the video
            videoclip.x = (stage.stageWidth/2)-(videoclip.width/2);
            videoclip.y = (stage.stageHeight/2)-(videoclip.height/2);
            videoclip.width = 1024;
            videoclip.height = 768;
            videoclip.autoPlay = true;
            videoclip.skin = "MinimaSilverPlayBackSeekMute.swf";
            videoclip.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,videoComplete);
            addChild(videoclip);
            videoclip.play('video/' + VIDEOS[button_index]);
            //trace ('video/' + VIDEOS[button_index])
        }

        private function videoComplete(event:Event):void 
        {
            removeChild(videoclip);         
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot is 1920px x 1080px. If that is the size of the stage, then button 9 / 10 are outside of the visible area.

Comment: Silly me. I did not notice that I switched the x and y with these two buttons. Thanks for making me aware of this. ;)

Then it rests only the problems loading the FLV. Maybe any ideas on that?

Comment: Set the width and height of the videoclip before calculating the position.

Comment: Thanks, That works like a charm. 
And adding a dropshadow?

Comment: In the constructor ('Main'), type `videoclip.filters = [ new DropShadowFilter() ];`, that should do it.